# An issue with jQuery $.isArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I have this ajax post, works perfectly fine so it runs the function `test` passing `data` to it.

```
$("#formID").submit(function (event) {
    $('#postError').html('').hide();
    $('#postInfo').html('loading results').show();
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $("#formID").attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize()
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#postInfo').html('').hide();
                test(data);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                $('#postInfo').html('').hide();
                console.log(1);
           });
})
```

And this is where it goes wrong,

```
function test(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if ($.isArray(data)){
        $('#postSuccess').html(data).show();
    }else {
        $('#postError').html(data).show();
    }
}
```

this is what I get in my console.log:

```
 [{"a1":"1","a1amount":"300","a2":"2","a2amount":"300","a3":"3","a3amount":"300"
 ,"a4":"4","a4amount":"300","a5":"5","a5amount":"60"}, 
 {"b1":"6","b1amount":"75","b2":"7","b2amount":"75","b3":"8","b3amount":"75"}, 
 {"c1":"9","c1amount":"40","c2":"10","c2amount":"40","c3":"11","c3amount":"40"," c4":"12","c4amount":"40"}]
```

This is a normal json array right or am I wrong?
if I'm right then I want to know why it runs the else part 
and if I'm wrong then I want to know whats wrong with the function or array.

Comment: I'm sure you are getting a string back not an array. i.e: `'[{"a1":"1","a1amount":"300","a2":"2","a2amount":"300","a3":"3","a3amount":"300"
 ,"a4":"4","a4amount":"300","a5":"5","a5amount":"60"}, 
 {"b1":"6","b1amount":"75","b2":"7","b2amount":"75","b3":"8","b3amount":"75"}, 
 {"c1":"9","c1amount":"40","c2":"10","c2amount":"40","c3":"11","c3amount":"40"," c4":"12","c4amount":"40"}]'` - However, `Console.log(data)` prints it like an object. You need to parse the string to an object first. using `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: yes, it worked indeed thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls.

your function `test()` change it to keep this working

```
function test(data) {
    var res = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(res);
    if ($.isArray(res)){
        $('#postSuccess').html(data).show();
    }else {
        $('#postError').html(data).show();
    }
}
```

The root cause is that you are getting the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the server, the best solution would be to include a header for `Content-Type: application/json` in the response.  This way the `$.ajax(...)` call will know how to handle your data when it receives it.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type for the gory details.

If you don't have access to the server side code, you can add a property called `dataType` to your ajax request as demonstrated below.  This will prevent the need to `JSON.parse(...)` all the responses.

**Example 1**

In this example, I'm demonstrating what your server is currently doing.  The example API server returns the correct header so I had to set the `dataType: 'html'` to emulate your server.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    dataType: 'html'
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    test(data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log(1);
  });

function test(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if ($.isArray(data)) {
    console.log("array :-)")
  } else {
    console.log("no array :-(")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Example 2**

Here is an example demonstrating how you could set `dataType: 'json'` to make the data in the callback match your intended data format.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    dataType: 'json' // set dataType to 'JSON'
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    test(data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log(1);
  });

function test(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if ($.isArray(data)) {
    console.log("array :-)")
  } else {
    console.log("no array :-(")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
function test(data) {
    console.log(data);

    if ($.isArray(JSON.parse(data))){
        $('#postSuccess').html(data).show();
    }else {
        $('#postError').html(data).show();
    }
}
```

Use JavaScript isArray() function instead of jQuery. It's support all type of browsers. here I add example code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.innerHTML = Array.isArray(fruits);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to check if "fruits" is an array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = 'mango';
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.innerHTML = Array.isArray(fruits);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to check if "fruits" is an array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```